# salt '*' win_wua.available returns Unknown Failure

Tags: salt-stack

I want to list all the available updates on a windows instance when I run "salt '*' win_wua.available" form salt master, I get the response below.

XXXXXXXX01:
    ERROR: Unknown Failure: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2145107934), None)

win_wua.list_updates also results in the same error

salt 'XXXXXXXX01' win_wua.list_updates
XXXXXXXX01:
    ERROR: Unknown Failure: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2145107934), None)

Please help

using minion 2017.7.5 and latest version of the salt master

Comment: Does the Salt Minion work correctly otherwise?

Comment: yes, all other commands do not have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with windows update and was returning WindowsUpdate_80244022, resolving it has resolved the issue with the salt call.